# Does a tetrahedron(regular) expose or project the same area on a 2D plane?

Tags: geometry

Does a tetrahedron(regular) always expose or project the same area on a 2D plane when tetrahedron is randomly rotated?
How to prove it? Matrices?

Comment: Suppose the length of an edge is $e$. When a face of the tetrahedron is parallel to the plane, the projection is an equilateral triangle with sides $e$; when two opposite edges of the tetrahedron are parallel to the plane, the projection is a square with diagonals $e$. The areas of these two projections are not equal.

Answer (score 0):

No, it will not always project the same area onto a 2D plane because it does not have infinite fold symmetry, like a sphere (though that probably isn't the only requirement).

You should be able to prove this using vectors, matrices and integrals (look up orthographic projection).

Depending on your purposes, you may also wish to look up "Perspective Projections", since, if this is for any form of computer art, projections which take perspective into account behave differently with respect to distance/scale.

It may help to imagine how the Pythagorean relationship of any of the sides of the tetrahedon change with respect to the plane.  For example, if I were to lay a toothpick onto a flat surface so that the toothpick is parallel to the plane, just beneath a lightsource, and then slowly raise one end of the toothpick off the plane while leaving the other end in contact with the plane, the relationship between the fixed length of the toothpick and the height of the lifted end would determine the length of the toothpick's shadow via the Pythagorean theorem.

This relationship also governs, in a much more complicated way, how the shadow of a tetrahedron will change in size and shape when it is twisted in space.